# Forward numbered error in inline procedure through outside try catch

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i am trying to validate my procedure values and throw custom exception because of the needed number in DAL / CRUD Layer. This works aswell as my example shows. My Problem with this is I **will not** throw same exception again just because i have a outer try catch for other use, btw catching exceptions that not expected. Any ideas? I was trying to working with error_message after inner throw because this is with substitue Parameter included. But i cant throw again with Message **AND** my specific number. For example **50101**.

```
create procedure dbo.ValidateString (
@Value nvarchar(max) output,
@Column varchar(100)
) 
as
begin
set nocount on;
begin try
    begin tran;

    if @Value is null
    begin
        raiserror (50201, 11, 0, @Column, @Value);
    end

    set @Value = ltrim(rtrim(@Value));

    if datalength(@Value) = 0
    begin
        raiserror (50211, 11, 0, @Column, @Value);
    end

    commit tran;
    return 0;
end try
begin catch
    if @@trancount > 0
    begin
        rollback tran;
    end

    if error_number() = 50201
    begin
        --argument null
        raiserror (50201, 11, 0, @Column, @Value);
        return 1;
    end

    if error_number() = 50211
    begin
        --argument
        raiserror (50211, 11, 0, @Column, @Value);
        return 1;
    end

    declare 
        @errorMessage nvarchar(max) = error_message(),
        @errorSeverity int = error_severity(),
        @errorState int = error_state();
    raiserror (@errorMessage, @errorSeverity, @errorState);
    return 1;
end catch
set nocount off;
end
go
```

---

```
create procedure dbo.InsertData (
@Name varchar(60),
@Active bit = null
)
as
begin
set nocount on;
begin try
    begin tran;

    exec dbo.ValidateString @Name output, 'Name';

    insert into dbo.tblTest (ID, Name, Active)
        values (newid(), @Name, isnull(@Active, 'false'));

    if @@rowcount = 1
    begin
        commit tran;
        return 0;
    end

    rollback tran;
    return 1;
end try
begin catch
    if @@trancount > 0
    begin
        rollback tran;
    end

    if error_number() = 50201
    begin
        --argument null
        raiserror (50201, 11, 0, 'Name', @Name);
        return 1;
    end

    if error_number() = 50211
    begin
        --argument
        raiserror (50311, 11, 0, 'Name', @Name);
        return 1;
    end

    declare 
        @errorMessage nvarchar(max) = error_message(),
        @errorSeverity int = error_severity(),
        @errorState int = error_state();
    raiserror (@errorMessage, @errorSeverity, @errorState);
    return 1;
end catch
set nocount off;
end
go
```

Comment: You can put your number in the message (concatenate it with the original error message) and separate the number from the message in the DAL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But thats the same if i throw just a error with message - no number. I will not use contains and string parse functions in my DAL. Just a equal  = number because of Performance.

Comment: Errors should not happen very often, so performance should not be a big issue for error handling.

Comment: Depends on how much use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining custom errors, set he message text to use parameters. This way you can pass a new text every time you re-throw the error in nested try-catch scenarios.

```
sp_addmessage @msgnum = 50005,
              @severity = 11,
              @msgtext = N'Message given: <<%30.20s>>'

GO             
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_inner_ex AS
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @error INT = 50005
    PRINT 'Raising inner'
    RAISERROR (@error, -- Message id.
               11, -- Severity,
               1, -- State,
               N'Inner error message');
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_outer_ex AS
BEGIN 
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC dbo.sp_inner_ex
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @error INT = ERROR_NUMBER()
        PRINT 'Raising outer'
        RAISERROR (@error, -- Message id.
                   11, -- Severity,
                   1, -- State,
                   N'Outer error message');
    END CATCH
END
GO
    EXEC dbo.sp_outer_ex
GO
    sp_dropmessage @msgnum = 50005; 
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_inner_ex
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_outer_ex
GO
```

Expected output:

```
Raising inner
Raising outer
Msg 50005, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_outer_ex, Line 42
Message given: <<           Outer error message>>
```

Keep in mind the following:

> [sp_addmessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SP_ADDMESSAGE_TSQL);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) Is the ID of the message. msg_id is int with a default of NULL. msg_id for user-defined error messages can be an integer between 50,001 and 2,147,483,647. The combination of msg_id and language must be unique; an error is returned if the ID already exists for the specified language.

You can only throw custom errors, not system ones.

> [RAISERROR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(RAISERROR_TSQL);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) ...a user-defined error message number stored in the sys.messages catalog view using sp_addmessage. Error numbers for user-defined error messages should be greater than 50000. When msg_id is not specified, RAISERROR raises an error message with an error number of 50000.